# docker python simplehhtpserver not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, simplehttpserver

my python codes

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_

from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
import SocketServer

class testHTTPSERVER_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>")

def run(server_class=HTTPServer,handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    print('starting server ....')
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1',8081)
    httpd = server_class(server_address,testHTTPSERVER_RequestHandler)
    print('running server')
    httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

and docker file

```
FROM python:2.7-onbuild
#python:2.7.13-alpine dene
ADD testhttp_server.py /src/app/testhttp_server.py
WORKDIR /src/app/
EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["python","testhttp_server.py"]
```

[docker run and logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1YpU.png)

[mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg0mW.png)

so where is my mistake??I'm working on that during two days but I didn't find anything else

Comment: also can you tell us how do you run your docker? is it docker for win? is it docker in a vm of some sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
server_address = ('127.0.0.1',8081)
```

to

```
server_address = ('0.0.0.0',8081)
```

Listening to `127.0.0.1` inside docker container means you want to listen to traffic generated from inside the container only but when you map a host to container. It is sending the traffic from host to the IP of the container. Which id dynamic and not know before hand. So you need to listen to all interfaces inside the container. And that is why you should use `0.0.0.0`

Comment: launch a normal nginx container and see if that works for you or not?

Comment: @FATİHİLGİN are you still getting the same error? also can you add output of docker ps and docker inspect py to your question.

Comment: I would like to work with apache so I haven't tried with nginx.I'll try .
docker-ps -->  http://imgur.com/a/yajQl     docker-                                                                               inspect-->http://imgur.com/a/dml6i

Comment: @FATİHİLGİN if you're using docker for win you will be able to access your containers only on the docker internal address, so 172.17.0.* - you can see it in inspect

Comment: I tried with the above image and it works great for me. `vagrant@vagrant:~/test3$ docker run -it -p 81:8081 test
starting server ....
running server
192.168.33.1 - - [09/Aug/2017 11:31:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.33.1 - - [09/Aug/2017 11:31:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -`. Make sure to build a clean one using `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: so my docker is working on win .this problem'll be ok if I set linux to my docker  .Am I right?

Comment: If you use Docker for windows then you don't test in localhost:81. Then you test in the Docker VM IP. Which is usually `192.168.99.100` on mac. You can check your IP using `ifconfig`. Use the that IP:81 and not `localhost:81`

Comment: Nothing except `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: No error.I can't see output on browser.I'll try --no-cache

Comment: Your browser is also running in Linux machine?

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Lalwani and everyone .It's working now